# Laravel - Guardar datos en sesión en el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Tengo un controlador con este código en un método y me da una excepción que en otro controlador no me da, lo pongo porque lo he repasado 10 veces y no veo el fallo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Session;
use App\Register;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->put('logged', true);
    }
}
```

La excepción que me da es esta

> Session store not set on request.

Comment: ¿Tienen algo de distinto las dos rutas? La que funciona y la que no.

Comment: La ruta que me funciona esta definida en el fichero web.php de esta forma Route::post('post-login', 'Front\AuthController@postLogin');

Comment: La ruta que NO me funciona está definida en el fichero api.php de esta forma

Route::post('/registers', 'API\RegisterController@store')->name('api.registers.store');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo una solicitud a un API, por lo cual no tienes ni sesión, ni CSRF, entre otros que sí están incluidos en el middleware de las rutas que defines en web.php

Lo que podrías hacer si definitivamente necesitas utilizarlo de esa manera, es agregar los Middleware correspondientes al grupo API:

```
'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

Comment: gracias @Shaz , creo que tendré que replantear ...porque una API tiene que ser sin estado no tiene sentido ponerle sesiones. gracias por todo.